# Qt Designer How to have multiple frames?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I would like to make a program with Qt Designer. Of course, programs can be complex. Mine would have several frames, which the user can cycle through using the Next and Back buttons.

How can I make these frames inside Qt Designer without making a .ui file for each of them then manually connect them? And is there a way in Qt Designer to switch to a particular frame upon button click?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a QStackedWidget (listed as "Stacked Widget" in the widget box). Except for widgets supporting integer input (QSpinBox), for which you can directly connect the `valueChanged` signal to the `setCurrentIndex()` slot in Designer, all the switching has to be done programmatically.

Comment: Thank you! I just searched it up, and I found an excellent [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFw-erSp3W8) discussing its usage as well as how to switch between different frames on button click. Serendipitous!

Comment: Ok. A couple of suggestions though: 1. don't rely too much on YouTube tutorials (there's specifically one published by a "Code First with Hala" that you should absolutely avoid): test it on your own, and most importantly study the documentation; 2. I hadn't the opportunity to fully watch the video you linked, but it seems missing a *very* important aspect, which is the usage of [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (which you can also use [in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)), which should almost *always* be used as fixed geometries are always discouraged.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I appreciate it. My plan was indeed to make a program with fixed geometries, but after learning about layout managers and the value of a responsive program, I’ve changed my mind. Out of curiosity, what is wrong about the Hala channel? Is it that she approaches Qt Designer from a simplistic POV?

Comment: It has many issues and suggests lots of bad (if not terrible) practices. They completely ignore layouts (they don't even consider them, nor mention their utmost importance), they add QDialogs (which are inteded as top level widgets, press Esc and see) to a stacked widget, there are security issues, lots of typos (some eventually corrected during the video but never pointed out) and code styling issues. There are other slightly less important aspects, but the above should give enough reasons to avoid that tutorial completely (which is a pity, because for some aspects it wasn't that bad at all).

Comment: The "simplistic approach" is not a problem, but when teaching (tutorials including) the simplicity should be a perception of the student, and never ignore important aspects that should be introduced first and explained with responsibility and awareness. Teaching is difficult, teaching well is incredibly hard, and not anybody can do it. The willingness to teach is admirable as much as the consciousness of saying "I'd like to do it, but I shouldn't". We get about a question a week here with issues caused by that tutorial.